# Why is my while loop not terminating when i < 0?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, while-loop

sorry for the noob question.
I have the following code for an assignment in my class (includes the assignment description):

> Write a program which asks the user to enter a string and then passes it to a void recursive function which displays the string in reverse. The prototype of the function would be:
>
> ```
> void reverse(string s, int i);
> ```
>
> The function call would be:
>
> ```
> reverse(strIn, strIn.length());
> ```
>
> A typical run will be:
>
> Enter a string:
>
> Four score and seven years ago ..
>
> .. oga sraey neves dna erocs ruoF

```
// Actual code
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void reverse(std::string, int);

int main() {
  std::string input;

  std::cout << "Enter a string." << std::endl;

  getline(std::cin, input);

  int i = input.length() - 1;

  reverse(input, i);

  return 0;
}

void reverse(std::string input, int i) {
  while (i >= 0) {
    std::cout << input.at(i);
    i--;
    reverse(input, i);
  }
}
```

I assumed that by subtracting 1 each time would display the last character in the string, and setting the loop condition to `i >= 0` would make the loop terminate when there's no more characters left in the string. But I'm getting the following output:

```
sleepy@mooncell ~/CMPSC121/Activities $ ./a.out
Enter a string.
help
plehhehhlehhehh
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: your loop does terminate... the problem is that the logic of your program require an `if` and not a `while`

Comment: You don't need a loop when using recursion

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff Thank you, that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to perform recursion and a while loop at the same time, just get rid of the while loop and it will work, the code should look something like this:

```
// Actual code
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void reverse(std::string, int);

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Enter a string." << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, input);
    int i = input.length() - 1;
    reverse(input, i);
    return 0;
}
void reverse(std::string input, int i) {
    if(i <0)
        return;
    std::cout << input.at(i);
    i--;
    reverse(input, i);
}
```

Comment: What caused the function to continue outputting characters?  I'm trying to figure out how it outputted those characters but struggling to envision it.

Comment: @bbchan this is because you are trying to perform a recursion and still in a while loop, i suggest you try using pen and paper to see what's wrong this is the best way to learn

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
void reverse(std::string input, int i) {
  while (i >= 0) {
    std::cout << input.at(i);
    i--;
    reverse(input, i);
  }
}
```

is not pure recursive because it uses a while loop.

Also it is a bad idea to pass the string by value. And the position in the string should have the type std::string::size_type.

The second parameter can have a default argument. in this case a function call will look much simpler

```
reverse( input );
```

Pay attention to that these statements can invoke undefined behavior when an empty string is passed to the function

```
int i = input.length() - 1;

reverse(input, i);
```

Because in this case the variable i will have maximum value. That is this declaration

```
int i = input.length() - 1;
```

in fact will be equivalent to

```
int i = std::string::size_type( -1 );
```

What you need is the following

```
void reverse( const std::string &s, std::string::size_type i = 0 ) 
{
    if ( i < s.size() )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        reverse( s, i + 1 );
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void reverse( const std::string &s, std::string::size_type i = 0 ) 
{
    if ( i < s.size() )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        reverse( s, i + 1 );
        std::cout << c;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "Hello bbchan";

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    reverse( s );

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello bbchan
nahcbb olleH
```

And even better to define the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. In this case you can for example write a string in the reverse order in a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::ostream & reverse( const std::string &s, 
                        std::string::size_type i = 0, 
                        std::ostream &os = std::cout ) 
{
    if ( i < s.size() )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        reverse( s, i + 1, os );
        os << c;
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "Hello bbchan";

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    reverse( s ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is recursive though … because it calls itself. Just bad logic.

Comment: Just changing the `while` to an `if` in the OP's function works just as well, and is far simpler.

Comment: @AdrianMole It is not simpler. It requires to specify the length of the string.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the cleaned up code.  I'm trying to learn the best practices but it's difficult on my own! (I don't get much input from the professor-- in fact I don't get any)

Comment: In the OP's assignment, this is stated: *"The function call would be: `reverse(strIn, strIn.length());`."*

Comment: @AdrianMole It is just a bad approach. And the function declaration is  void reverse(string s, int i);. It means that it is not necessary it must be called as you said.